# A verb to use for "fidelity"?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Translators are obligated to ______ fidelity.

What verb is the most idiomatic one for the above sentence. I have *observe* and *respect* in mind. Are they any good?

Comment: Is anything wrong with "remain faithful to the original"?

Comment: *To inspire fidelity?*

Comment: 'Manifest', 'demonstrate' and 'maintain' are possible, but Andrew's answer is doubtless the most idiomatic.

Comment: @AndrewLeach No, but I want a verb to use with "fidelity"! Is that way you mentioned more idiomatic?

Answer (score 4):

How about [**ensure**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ensure)? From M-W:

**ensure**: to make sure, certain, or safe

Your example sentence:

> *Translators are obligated to **ensure** the fidelity of their translations to the original sources.*

Comment: I was going to suggest *practise*, which is the most common pairing with *fidelity* in general, but then realized that the sentence is more likely referring to the fidelity of the text than it is to the fidelity of the translators (in their romantic relationships, for example). Which is exactly the emphasis you used when adding additional words to the sentence. Another sense, which isn't suggested in the sentence at all, is *[dedicated] to **textual** fidelity*.